# Expected behavior of sklearn pairwise_distances with force_all_finite = False?

Tags: scikit-learn, nan

I am attempting to use sklearn's pairwise_distances on arrays containing NaNs without filling the NaNs.
Minmal code example to reproduce the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

X = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[1,np.nan]])
res = pairwise_distances(X, force_all_finite=False)
```

returns

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

The behavior with force_all_finite=True is identical. I would instead prefer that distances to points with NaNs will instead simply be NaN themselves. I expected that this would be the behavior with the option force_all_finite = False, however the same ValueError is raised regardless of how force_all_finite is set, making me wonder what the expected behavior of this option really is? Any ideas for workarounds?

Windows 10 with Anaconda Python 3.7.3, sklearn 0.2.22.post1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to my problem, perhaps this could be useful to other users of sklearn pairwise_distances with nan values:

It turns out scipy cdist/pdist already has the functionality I was missing, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

X = np.array([[1,2],
              [2,3],
              [np.nan,np.nan]])
res = cdist(X,X)
```

gives

```
array([[0.        , 1.41421356,        nan],
       [1.41421356, 0.        ,        nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan]])
```

as desired.